# C++ method call and type scope resolution ambiguity

Tags: c++, types, scope, ambiguity, method-call

I hope the title actually describes what I wanted to ask...

I wrote a piece of code that compiles with gcc and works as I intended.  However, it does not compile with llvm and the code executes differently when compiled with icc!
Here is an example of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

class A {
public:
  virtual void foo() { cout << "A::foo()" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  typedef A  base;
  virtual void foo() { cout << "B::foo()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  typedef B  base;
  base* bp = new B();
  bp->base::foo(); 
}
```

gcc output:  A::foo()
icc output:  B::foo()

Could somebody explain what does the standard say about this case?

Comment: I would say it's a bug in GCC and ICC, as `B::base` is not a _member_ of `B`, which means that it shouldn't be possible to access it as a member (`bp->base`).

Comment: I agree with @JoachimPileborg, moreover `base` could be interpreted as B in this scope. Have you compiled with Warnings flags? (-Wall for gcc)

Comment: Isn't it just undefined behaviour, because `main` is not of the required form? Looks like all compilers are right.

Comment: @Nawaz: Are you sure ? I never could wrap my head in the name lookup rules; Clang considers that the two `base` are ambiguous and does not prefer one over the other. I really wish we would have an authoritative answer here, 3 compilers - 3 behaviors... it's a weird piece for sure.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Okay, it should now be ready to use... and still you'll get the issue.

Comment: You could post a comment on [STL's series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-1-of-n), which is all about name lookup.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: OK, *now* it's a bug :-)

Comment: What gcc version are you using? The code you pasted fails to compile in all versions of gcc I have available (4.3.4 through 4.7.0). Did you maybe compile some other code, and just showing a praphrasation of it here?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Really? The code seems to compile and run on ideone, which uses gcc 4.3.4: http://ideone.com/daJbT. It also works if you enable c++11, using gcc 4.5.1 : http://ideone.com/KT1Jj.

Comment: @LucTouraille: If you compare the post edits with the timestamp of my comment, taking into account that it takes a while to write it, you would notice that at the time of writing, there was code that did not compile.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Ok, I thought your comment was in response to Matthieu's edit, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: So... it seems that there is a bug in both Clang and icc and that gcc got it right. Anyone has a fresh copy of Clang to test on the trunk ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From C++11, §3.4.5/4:

> If the id-expression in a class member access is a qualified-id of the
> form
>
> ```
>     class-name-or-namespace-name::...
> ```
>
> the class-name-or-namespace-name
> following the . or -> operator is first looked up in the class of the
> object expression and the name, if found, is used. Otherwise it is
> looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression.

I don't think it can be clearer.  This finds `B::base`, so the output
should be `A::foo()`.

Comment: Thank you for help, you guys are awesome. This particular paragraph is indeed very clear and exactly to the point!

Answer (score 6):

I think this part of the standard is relevant:

> 3.4.3.1 Class members [class.qual]
>
> 1) If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the name specified after the
>   nested-namespecifier is looked up in the scope of the class (10.2),
>   except for the cases listed below. The name shall represent one or
>   more members of that class or of one of its base classes (Clause 10).
>   [ Note: A class member can be referred to using a qualified-id at any
>   point in its potential scope (3.3.7). —end note ] The exceptions to
>   the name lookup rule above are the following:
>
> — a destructor name is
>   looked up as specified in 3.4.3;
>
> — a conversion-type-id of a
>   conversion-function-id is looked up in the same manner as a
>   conversion-type-id in a class member access (see 3.4.5);
>
> — the names
>   in a template-argument of a template-id are looked up in the context
>   in which the entire postfix-expression occurs.
>
> — the lookup for a name
>   specified in a using-declaration (7.3.3) also finds class or
>   enumeration names hidden within the same scope (3.3.10).

`base::` in this case seems to "nominate" a class, so the look up is done in scope of the class. I don't see how any of the exception cases could apply, so it is the scope of the class, as such `base` is equivalent to `A`.

(5.1.1-8 indicates that it is a qualified-id in that case and that 3.4.3.1 applies)

Comment: Agreed.  It seems quite clear to me as well.  The code is correct, well defined, and the output should be `A::foo`.